# Is there a closed-form solution for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(3n+m)}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, closed-form

I am seeking a closed-form solution for this double sum:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(\color{blue}{3}n+m)}= ?.
\end{eqnarray*}

I will turn it into $3$ tough integrals in a moment.  But first I will state some similar results:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(n+m)} &=& 2 \zeta(3) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(\color{blue}{2}n+m)} &=& \frac{11}{8} \zeta(3) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(\color{blue}{4}n+m)} &=& \frac{67}{32} \zeta(3) -\frac{G \pi}{2}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

where $G$ is the Catalan constant. The last result took some effort ...

Now I know most of you folks prefer integrals to sums, so lets turn this into an integral. Using

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n} &=& \int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx\\
\frac{1}{m} &=& \int_0^1 y^{m-1} dy\\
\frac{1}{3n+m} &=& \int_0^1 z^{3n+m-1} dz \\
\end{eqnarray*}
and summing the geometric series, we have the following triple integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{z^3 dx dy dz}{(1-xz^3)(1-yz)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now doing the $x$ and $y$ integrations we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
I=\int_0^1  \frac{\ln(1-z) \ln(1-z^3)}{z} dz.
\end{eqnarray*}

Factorize the argument of the second logarithm ...

\begin{eqnarray*}
I= \underbrace{\int_0^1  \frac{\ln(1-z) \ln(1-z)}{z} dz}_{=2\zeta(3)} + \int_0^1  \frac{\ln(1-z) \ln(1+z+z^2)}{z} dz.
\end{eqnarray*}

So if you prefer my question is ... find a closed form for:

\begin{eqnarray*}
I_1 = - \int_0^1  \frac{\ln(1-z) \ln(1+z+z^2)}{z} dz.
\end{eqnarray*}

Integrating by parts gives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
I_1 = - \int_0^1  \frac{\ln(z) \ln(1+z+z^2)}{1-z} dz + \int_0^1  \frac{(1+2z)\ln(z) \ln(1-z)}{1+z+z^2} dz.
\end{eqnarray*}

and let us call these integrals $I_2$ and $I_3$ respectively.

All $3$ of these integrals are not easy for me to evaluate and any help with their resolution will be gratefully received.

Comment: When I tried Wolfram ... it just told me $I_1 =1.10925$ , $I_2=0.713975$ and $I_3=0.395273$ ... at least it adds up !

Comment: *Mathematica* gives the closed-form solution:  $\frac{1}{54} \left(-6 \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)
   \text{HypergeometricPFQRegularized}^{(\{0,0,0,0\},\{0,0,1\},0)}\left(\left\{1,1,1,\frac{4}{3}\right\},\left\{2,2,\frac{4}{3}\right\},1\right)-6 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)
   \text{HypergeometricPFQRegularized}^{(\{0,0,0,0\},\{0,0,1\},0)}\left(\left\{1,1,1,\frac{5}{3}\right\},\left\{2,2,\frac{5}{3}\right\},1\right)+12 \zeta (3)+2 \gamma  \pi
   ^2+\pi ^2 \log (27)\right)$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks David ... I had a feeling $ \ln 3$ would be in the answer somewhere ... now I need to look up PFQ-Regularised Hypergeometrics ... The

Comment: Try this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+ln(1-x)ln(1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2)%2Fx

Comment: The sequence double sums are of the form $$\frac{1}{a}\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{a m}}{n^2}$$ where $H_n$ is the Harmonic Number and $n=am$; $a$ being equal to $1$,$2$,$3$ or $4$.

Comment: Mathematica gives for the integral $$I=\frac{1}{216} \left(-216 \left(\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{\sqrt[6]{-1}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(-\frac{(-1)^{5/6}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)+672 \zeta (3)+9 \log ^3(3)-15 \pi ^2 \log (3)+4 \pi  \sqrt{3} \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: You probably won't be voted to close for not showing your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: [This generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301156/the-closed-form-solution-of-the-family-sum-n-1-infty-sum-m-1-infty) may be of interest.

Answer (score 13):

A slightly different approach where I will make use of a particular *Euler sum*.

Let
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \ln (1 - x^3)}{x} \, dx.$$
Expanding the $\ln (1 - x^3)$ term gives
\begin{align}
I &= - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^1 x^{3n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx\tag1
\end{align}
Making use of the result (for a proof of this, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263927/prove-frac-partial-partial-m-textbn-m-textbn-m-sum-k-0n-1-f/3267101#3267101))
$$\int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx = -\frac{H_n}{n}.$$
Re-indexing, namely $n \mapsto 3n$ gives
$$\int_0^1 x^{3n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx = -\frac{H_{3n}}{3n}.$$
Substitution of this result into (1) reduces our integral $I$ to the following Euler sum
$$I = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_{3n}}{n^2} = 3 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_{3n}}{(3n)^2}.$$

For the Euler sum, since the series converges absolutely, terms in the sum may be rearranged. Doing so we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n =1}^\infty \frac{H_{3n}}{(3n)^2} &= \frac{H_3}{3^2} + \frac{H_6}{6^2} + \frac{H_9}{9^2} + \cdots\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \left [\frac{3}{2} \frac{H_3}{3^2} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{H_6}{6^2} + \frac{3}{2} \frac{H_9}{9^2} + \cdots \right ]\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \left [\left (\frac{H_3}{3^2} + \frac{H_6}{6^2} + \frac{H_9}{9^2} + \cdots \right ) + \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{H_3}{3^2} + \frac{H_6}{6^2} + \frac{H_9}{9^2} + \cdots \right ) \right ]\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \left [\left (-\frac{1}{2} \frac{H_1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{H_2}{2^2} + \frac{H_3}{3^2} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{H_4}{4^2} - \frac{1}{2} \frac{H_5}{5^2} + \frac{H_6}{6^2} - \cdots \right )\right.\\
& \qquad + \left. \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{H_1}{1^2} + \frac{H_2}{2^2} + \frac{H_3}{3^2} + \frac{H_4}{4^2} + \cdots \right ) \right ]\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} \cos \left (\frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right ) + \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} \tag2\\
&= \frac{2}{3} \zeta (3) + \frac{2}{3} \operatorname{Re} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} \left (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}} \right )^n
\end{align} 
Note in (2) the well-known result of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^2} = 2 \zeta (3)$ has been used.

The sum can now be found by making use of the following generating function (for a simple proof of this result, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604316/infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nn22n/605602#605602))
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}x^n=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3).$$
Setting $x = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$ gives
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_{3n}}{(3n)^2} &= \frac{2}{3} \zeta (3) + \frac{2}{3} \operatorname{Re} \left [\operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) - \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) + \ln (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right.\\
& \qquad \left. + \frac{1}{2} \ln (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \ln^2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) + \zeta (3) \right ]\\
&= \frac{5}{3} \zeta (3) + \frac{2}{3} \operatorname{Re} \left [\operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) - \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) + \ln (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right.\\
& \qquad \left. + \frac{\pi i}{3} \ln^2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ]\tag3
\end{align}
Now, since (this part is tedious, but readily doable)
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= -\frac{4}{9} \zeta (3)\\
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= \frac{\pi^2}{18} \ln 3 + \frac{13}{18} \zeta (3)\\
\operatorname{Re} \left [i \ln^2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ] &= \frac{\pi}{6} \ln 3\\
\operatorname{Re} \left [\ln (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ] &= \frac{\pi^3}{27 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{\pi}{18 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right )
\end{align}
The Euler sum in (3) thus becomes
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_{3n}}{(3n)^2} = \frac{5}{9} \zeta (3) + \frac{2 \pi^3}{81 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{\pi}{27 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ),$$ 
so that we finally arrive at the following value for the integral (and hence your double sum) of

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \ln (1 - x^3)}{x} \, dx = \frac{5}{3} \zeta (3) + \frac{2 \pi^3}{27 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{\pi}{9 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right )$$

Comment: (+1) Good. In general, as stated very often in the book, (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series, use that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+n)}=\frac{H_n}{n}$. Thus, you may reduce much the size of the solution. You get directly $3 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_{3n}}{(3n)^2}$.

Comment: @omegadot would it be possible to tell me how to find (by hand) those real parts of the polylogarithms?

Comment: You may be interested in [this generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301156/the-closed-form-solution-of-the-family-sum-n-1-infty-sum-m-1-infty).

Comment: @Zacky - I calculate, by hand, the real parts of all those quantities I used in my answer in an *addendum* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294203/is-there-a-closed-form-solution-for-sum-n-1-infty-sum-m-1-infty-fr/3301313#3301313).

Answer (score 9):

$$\boxed{I=\int_0^1  \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln(1-x^3)}{x}dx=\frac53\zeta(3) +\frac{2\pi^3}{27\sqrt 3} -\frac{\pi}{9\sqrt 3}\psi_1\left(\frac13\right)}$$
As mentioned in the question we have:
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x+x^2)}{x}dx=2\zeta(3)+J$$

We can make use of the following series:
$$ -\frac12 \ln(1-2x\cos t+x^2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nt)}{n} x^n,\quad |x|<1, t\in \mathbb R$$
$$\Rightarrow J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x+x^2)}{x}dx=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\frac{2n \pi}{3}\right)}{n}\int_0^1 \ln(1-x) x^{n-1}dx $$
$$=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\frac{2n \pi}{3}\right)}{n^2}H_n=2\Re \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^2}H_n\right),\quad z=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$$
Using [the following generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/605602/515527):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}H_n=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\ln(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln x \ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$
And by plugging in the values found in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3301313/515527) yields the announced result, as we obtain:
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x+x^2)}{x}dx=\frac{2\pi^3}{27\sqrt 3}-\frac13\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi}{9\sqrt 3}\psi_1\left(\frac13\right)$$

Comment: One word: yikes (+1)

Answer (score 6):

The closed-forms for the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{\alpha n}}{n^2}$$
is known. It equals to
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^{2}+\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{2 \alpha} \sum_{k=1}^{\alpha-1} \cot \left(\frac{\pi k}{\alpha}\right) \psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{k}{\alpha}\right)$$
where
$\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ and $\psi^{(1)}$ denotes trigamma function.
For instances, let $\alpha=1,2,3,4,5,6$, then we get the following.
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{n^2}=2\zeta(3)\\
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{2n}}{n^2} = \frac{11}{4}\zeta(3)\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{3n}}{n^2}=5\zeta(3)-
\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3} } \left [ \psi^{(1)} \left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )
-\psi^{(1)} \left ( \frac{2}{3}  \right )
 \right ]\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{4n}}{n^2}=\frac{67}{8} \zeta(3)-2\pi G\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{5n}}{n^2}=\frac{64}{5} \zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{10\sqrt{5}}
 \left\{ 
\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5} }
\left [ \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{1}{5}  \right ) - \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{4}{5}  \right ) \right ]
 +
\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5} } \left [  \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{2}{5}  \right ) - \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{3}{5}  \right ) \right ] \right\}\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{6n}}{n^2}=\frac{73}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{12} \left \{ \sqrt{3}\left [
 \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{1}{6}  \right )- \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{5}{6}  \right ) \right ] 
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3} } \left [  \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )- \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{2}{3}  \right ) \right ] 
  \right \}
\end{aligned}$$

---

*Proof.*
Consider function($\psi^{(0)}$ denotes digamma function)
$$f(z)=\frac{\pi\cot(\pi z)(\gamma+\psi^{(0)}(-\alpha z))}{z^2} ,a\in\mathbb{N}^+.$$
We note that integral of $f(z)$ is decreasing like $z^{-1}$ at infinity, where a contour avoids the poles. Which allows us to apply residue calculation.
The residues are
$$\begin{aligned}
&\mathrm{Res}(f,-n)=\frac{H_{\alpha n}}{n^2} -\frac{1}{\alpha n^3}\\
&\mathrm{Res}(f,0)=-\alpha^2\zeta(3)\\
&\mathrm{Res}(f,n)=-\frac{2}{\alpha n^3} +\frac{H_{\alpha n}}{n^2} \\
&\mathrm{Res}(f,n/\alpha)=\cfrac{\pi\alpha\cot\left(\frac{\pi n}{\alpha} \right)}{n^2}. 
\end{aligned}$$
Summing over all of them, the result should be $0$. Consequently,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{\alpha n}}{n^2} =\frac{1}{2} 
\left ( \alpha^2+\frac{3}{\alpha}  \right ) \zeta(3)
-\frac{\pi\alpha}{2} \sum_{n=1,n\not{{\equiv}}0(\mathrm{mod }\alpha)}^{\infty} 
\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}  \right ) }{n^2}.$$
Now we want to derive an explicit expression,
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1,n\not{{\equiv}}0(\mathrm{mod}\alpha)}^{\infty} 
\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{\pi n}{\alpha}  \right ) }{n^2}\\&=
\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{1^2} 
+\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{2\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{2^2}
+\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{3\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{3^2}+...
+\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{(\alpha-1)\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{(\alpha-1)^2}\\
&+\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{(\alpha+1)^2}
+\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{2\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{(\alpha+2)^2}
+\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{3\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{(\alpha+3)^2}+...
+\frac{\cot\left ( \frac{(\alpha-1)\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) }{(2\alpha-1)^2}+...\\
&=\cot\left ( \frac{\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) 
\left [  \frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{(\alpha+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(\alpha+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(\alpha+3)^2}+...  \right ]\\
&+\cot\left ( \frac{2\pi}{\alpha}  \right ) \left[\frac{1}{2^2}+ \frac{1}{(2\alpha+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2\alpha+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(2\alpha+3)^2}+...  \right ]+...\\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha^2} \sum_{k=1}^{\alpha-1} \cot\left ( \frac{\pi k}{\alpha}  \right ) \psi^{(1)}\left (\frac{k}{\alpha}   \right ). 
\end{aligned}$$
Finally,
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{\alpha n}}{n^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^{2}+\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{2 \alpha} \sum_{k=1}^{\alpha-1} \cot \left(\frac{\pi k}{\alpha}\right) \psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{k}{\alpha}\right)}$$

In similar fashion, we have
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{\alpha n}}{n^{4}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha^{4}+\frac{5}{\alpha}\right) \zeta(5)-\frac{\pi^2\alpha^2}{6}\zeta(3) -\frac{\pi}{12 \alpha} \sum_{k=1}^{\alpha-1} \cot \left(\frac{\pi k}{\alpha}\right) \psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{k}{\alpha}\right)}$$
By expressing the $H_{kn}$ using integrals, interchanging the order, we cook up some interesting(and also beautiful) integrals.
$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x} \text{d}x=2\zeta(3)\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x} \text{d}x=-\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x} \text{d}x=\frac{23}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{2}G \\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x+x^2)}{x}\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{3} \zeta(3)-
\frac{\pi}{18\sqrt{3} } \left [ \psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )-\psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac{2}{3}  \right )\right ]\\ \\
& \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi^2}{3}\zeta(3)-3\zeta(5)\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)\text{Li}_2(x^2)}{x}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{37}{16}\zeta(5)\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)\text{Li}_2(x^3)}{x}\text{d}x=\frac{2\pi^2}{9}\zeta(3)-\frac{124}{27}\zeta(5)
+\frac{\pi}{324\sqrt{3} } \left [ \psi^{(3)}\left ( \frac{1}{3}  \right )-\psi^{(3)}\left ( \frac{2}{3}  \right )\right ]\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{Li}_2(x)\text{Li}_2(x^4)}{x}\text{d}x=\frac{5\pi^2}{24}\zeta(3)-\frac{1029}{128}\zeta(5)+2\pi\beta(4)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Only $2$ years late to the party ... But what a beautiful answer ... Thank you $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 5):

> Not a full answer, but another interesting expression for the series.

Let's introduce a function:

$$S(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^n y^m}{ n m (3n +m)}$$

Assuming $|x|<1$ and $|y|<1$ we avoid any convergence problems, and can use partial fractions:

$$S(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^n y^m}{ n m^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^n y^m}{ m^2(n+ \frac{1}{3} m)}$$

$$S(x,y)=-\log(1-x) \text{Li}_2(y) -x \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{y^m}{ m^2} \Phi \left(x,1,\frac13 m+1 \right)$$

Let's use the integral representation of the Lerch transcendent:

$$\Phi \left(x,1,\frac13 m+1 \right)= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(1+\frac13 m)t} ~dt}{1-x e^{-t}}$$

Summation under the integral gives us:

$$S(x,y)=-\log(1-x) \text{Li}_2(y) -x \int_0^\infty \text{Li}_2 \left(y e^{-t/3} \right) \frac{dt}{e^t-x}$$

So we can assume:

> $$S=\lim_{x \to 1} \left[-\log(1-x) \text{Li}_2(x) -x \int_0^\infty \text{Li}_2 \left(x e^{-t/3} \right) \frac{dt}{e^t-x} \right]$$

Which does seem to work numerically, though of course is quite hard to evaluate symbolically.

Numerical check:

```
In[22]:= x=9999999/10000000;
y=9999999/10000000;
N[-Log[1-x]PolyLog[2,y],10]-x NIntegrate[PolyLog[2,y Exp[-t/3]]/(Exp[t]-x),{t,0,Infinity},WorkingPrecision->10]
Out[24]= 1.29484017
```

Compare to exact expression:

```
In[25]:= N[(1/216)*(-15*Pi^2*Log[3] + 9*Log[3]^3 + 4*Sqrt[3]*Pi*(-PolyGamma[1, 1/3] + 
      PolyGamma[1, 2/3]) - 216*(PolyLog[3, (-1)^(1/6)/Sqrt[3]] + 
      PolyLog[3, -((-1)^(5/6)/Sqrt[3])]) + 672*Zeta[3]), 10]
Out[25]= 1.2948652620+0.*10^-11 I
```

---

It may be that $x=y$ is not the best choice for the limit. For example, we can assume $x=y^a$ where $a$ is some real number. A good choice may lead to a better numerical convergence or even a closed form.

Using the dilogarithm properties, we have:

$$F(x,y)=-x \int_0^\infty \text{Li}_2 \left(y e^{-t/3} \right) \frac{dt}{e^t-x}=x \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-e^{-t/3} y u) du dt}{u (e^t-x)}$$

Let's change the variable:

$$e^{-t}=v \\ t=- \log v$$

$$F(x,y)=x \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1- y u v^{1/3}) du dv}{u (1-x v)}$$

Let's take:

$$y=x^{1/3}$$

We have:

$$F(x,y)=x \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1- u (xv)^{1/3}) du dv}{u (1-x v)}$$

$$v=w/x$$

$$F(x,y)=\int_0^x \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1- u w^{1/3}) du dw}{u (1-w)}$$

$$F(x,y)=-\int_0^x \frac{\text{Li}_2 (w^{1/3}) dw}{1-w}$$

So, there's a neater expression for the limit:

> $$ \color{blue}{S=\lim_{x \to 1} \left[-\log(1-x) \text{Li}_2(x^{1/3}) -\int_0^x \frac{\text{Li}_2 (w^{1/3}) dw}{1-w} \right]}$$

---

This allows a simple generalization:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^n y^m}{ n m (an +m)}=\lim_{x \to 1} \left[-\log(1-x) \text{Li}_2(x^{1/a}) -\int_0^x \frac{\text{Li}_2 (w^{1/a}) dw}{1-w} \right]$$

Which checks out numerically with the examples from the OP.

I wonder if we can somehow use L'Hospital here to deal with the integral and get a closed form for the limit.

Integration by parts could also work.

Comment: In fact, integration by parts will immediately give us the same integral as in the OP

Answer (score 5):

**Addendum**

This is an addendum to the answer I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294203/is-there-a-closed-form-solution-for-sum-n-1-infty-sum-m-1-infty-fr/3294538#3294538). As requested by @Zacky, I will show how the real parts of those quantities considered in my solution, particularly those containing polylogarithms, can be extracted by hand. The quantities in question are:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re} \left [i \ln^2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ] &= \frac{\pi}{6} \ln 3\tag1\\
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= -\frac{4}{9} \zeta (3)\tag2\\
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= \frac{\pi^2}{18} \ln 3 + \frac{13}{18} \zeta (3)\tag3\\
\operatorname{Re} \left [\ln (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ] &= \frac{\pi^3}{27 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{\pi}{18 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right )\tag4
\end{align}

As we are dealing with complex valued functions, in all cases the principal value is taken.

*Preliminaries*

$$\ln \left (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}} \right ) = \frac{2 \pi i}{3}.$$

**The first quantity**

It is routine to show that:
$$\ln \left (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}} \right ) = \frac{1}{2} \ln 3 - i \frac{\pi}{6}.$$
Thus
\begin{align}
i \ln^2 \left (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}} \right ) &= i \left (\frac{1}{2} \ln 3 - i \frac{\pi}{6} \right )^2\\
&= i \left (\frac{1}{4} \ln^2 3 - \frac{\pi^2}{36} - i\frac{\pi}{6} \ln 3 \right )\\
&=\frac{\pi}{6} \ln 3 + \frac{i}{4} \ln^2 3 - \frac{i \pi^2}{36},
\end{align}
and we immediately see that
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Re} \left [i \ln^2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ] = \frac{\pi}{6} \ln 3}$$

**The second quantity**

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= \operatorname{Re} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{3}}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} \cos \left (\frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right )\\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1^3} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4^3} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{5^3} + \frac{1}{6^3} - \cdots\\
&= \frac{3}{2} \left (\frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{6^3} + \frac{1}{9^3} + \cdots \right ) - \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{1}{1^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \cdots \right )\\
&= \frac{3}{2 \cdot 3^3} \left (\frac{1}{1^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \cdots \right ) - \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{1}{1^3} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \cdots \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{18} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}\\
&= -\frac{4}{9} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} 
\end{align}
giving
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) = -\frac{4}{9} \zeta (3)}$$

Later we will have a need for its imaginary part so let's calculate it now.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Im} \operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= \operatorname{Im} \sum_{n = 1} \frac{1}{n^3} e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{3}}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} \sin \left (\frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right )\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \underbrace{\sum_{\substack{n = 1\\n \in 1,4,7,\ldots}}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}}_{n \, \mapsto \, 3n + 1} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \underbrace{\sum_{\substack{n = 1\\n \in 2,5,8,\ldots}}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}}_{n \, \mapsto \, 3n + 2}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n + 1)^3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n + 2)^3}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{54} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n + \frac{1}{3})^3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{54} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n + \frac{2}{3})^3}\\
&= -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{54} \cdot \frac{1}{2!} \psi^{(2)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{54} \cdot \frac{1}{2!} \psi^{(2)} \left (\frac{2}{3} \right )\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{108} \left [\psi^{(2)} \left (1 - \frac{1}{3} \right ) - \psi^{(2)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) \right ]\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{108} \cdot \pi \left. \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \cot (\pi z) \right |_{z = \frac{1}{3}}\\ 
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{108} \cdot \frac{8 \pi^2}{3 \sqrt{3}}\\
&= \frac{2 \pi^2}{81}. 
\end{align}
Thus we see that
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Li}_3 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}} ) = -\frac{4}{9} \zeta (3) + \frac{2 \pi^2}{81}i}$$

**The third quantity**

In order to evaluate this quantity we will make use of the following result (for a proof of this result, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052776/how-to-evaluate-the-sum/1053912#1053912))
$$\operatorname{Li}_{3}(z) + \operatorname{Li}_{3}(1-z)+ \operatorname{Li}_{3}\left(1 - \frac{1}{z}\right) = \zeta(3) + \frac{\ln^{3} (z)}{6}+ \frac{\pi^{2} \ln (z) }{6}- \frac{\ln^{2} (z) \ln(1-z)}{2}. \qquad (*)$$
If we set $z = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$, note that
$$1 - \frac{1}{z} = \overline{1 - z}.$$
Thus
$$\operatorname{Li}_3 \left (1 - \frac{1}{z} \right ) = \operatorname{Li}_3 (\overline{1 - z}) = \overline{\operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - z)},$$
allowing us to write
$$\operatorname{Li}_3 \left (1 - z \right ) + \operatorname{Li}_3 \left (1 - \frac{1}{z} \right ) = \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - z) + \overline{\operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - z)} = 2 \operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - z).$$
So ($*$) can be rewritten as
$$\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - z) = \frac{1}{2} \zeta (3) + \frac{1}{12} \ln^3 (z) + \frac{\pi^2}{12} \ln (z) - \frac{1}{4} \ln^2 (z) \ln (1 - z) - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Li}_3 (z).$$
Setting $z = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$, one has
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= \frac{1}{2} \zeta (3) - \frac{1}{12} \cdot \frac{8 i\pi^3}{27} + \frac{\pi^2}{12} \cdot \frac{2 \pi i}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{4 \pi^2}{9} \left (\frac{1}{2} \ln 3 - \frac{i \pi}{6} \right )\\
& \qquad - \frac{1}{2} \left (-\frac{4}{9} \zeta (3) + \frac{2 i \pi^3}{81} \right )\\
&= \frac{13}{18} \zeta (3) + \frac{\pi^2}{18} \ln 3
\end{align}
Thus
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_3 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) = \frac{13}{18} \zeta (3) + \frac{\pi^2}{18} \ln 3}$$

**The fourth quantity**

To evaluate this quantity we will make use of *Euler' reflexion formula*, namely
$$\operatorname{Li}_2 (z) + \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - z) = \zeta (2) - \ln (z) \ln (1 - z).$$
Setting $z = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$ we see that
$$\operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}) = \zeta (2) - \frac{2 \pi i}{3} \ln (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) - \operatorname{Li}_2 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \qquad (**)$$

Finding $\operatorname{Li}_2 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}})$. For the real part:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_2 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= \operatorname{Re} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{3}}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \cos \left (\frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right )\\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4^2} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{5^2} + \frac{1}{6^2} - \cdots\\
&=\frac{3}{2} \left (\frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{6^2} + \frac{1}{9^2} + \cdots \right ) - \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots \right )\\
&= \frac{3}{2 \cdot 3^2} \left (\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots \right ) - \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \cdots \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{6} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&= -\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&= -\frac{1}{3} \zeta (2),
\end{align}
giving
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Re} \operatorname{Li}_2 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) = -\frac{\pi^2}{18}}$$

While for the imaginary part:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Im} \operatorname{Li}_2 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) &= \operatorname{Im} \sum_{n = 1} \frac{1}{n^2} e^{\frac{2 \pi i n}{3}}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \sin \left (\frac{2 \pi n}{3} \right )\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \underbrace{\sum_{\substack{n = 1\\n \in 1,4,7,\ldots}}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}_{n \, \mapsto \, 3n + 1} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \underbrace{\sum_{\substack{n = 1\\n \in 2,5,8,\ldots}}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}}_{n \, \mapsto \, 3n + 2}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n + 1)^2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n + 2)^2}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{18} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n + \frac{1}{3})^2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{18} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n + \frac{2}{3})^2}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{18} \left [\psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) -\psi^{(1)} \left (1 - \frac{1}{3} \right ) \right ]\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{18} \left [\psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) - \left \{\frac{4 \pi^2}{3} - \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) \right \} \right ]\\
&= \frac{1}{3 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) - \frac{2}{9 \sqrt{3}} \pi^2
\end{align}
Thus we see that
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Li}_2 (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) = -\frac{\pi^2}{18} + \frac{i}{3 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) - \frac{2i \pi^2}{9 \sqrt{3}}}$$

So on making use of Euler's reflexion formula, we see that
$$\operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) = \frac{\pi^2}{9} - \frac{\pi i}{3} \ln 3 + \frac{2i}{9\sqrt{3}} - \frac{i}{3 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ).$$
So at last
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re} \left [\ln (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ] &= \operatorname{Re} \left [\left \{\frac{1}{2} \ln 3 - \frac{\pi i}{6} \right \} \right. \times \\
& \qquad  \left. \left \{\frac{\pi^2}{9} - \frac{\pi i}{3} \ln 3 + \frac{2i}{9\sqrt{3}} - \frac{i}{3 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ) \right \} \right ]\\
&= \frac{\pi^3}{27 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{\pi}{18 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right ).
\end{align}
Thus
$$\boxed{\operatorname{Re} \left [\ln (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}) \right ] = \frac{\pi^3}{27 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{\pi}{18 \sqrt{3}} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{3} \right )}$$